# Disable required attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, required

I have a class:

```
public class ShoppingParent : Parent 
{

}
```

Which implements this class:

```
public class Parent 
{

  public string Firstname { get; set;}

  public string Lastname { get; set;}

  public string Address { get; set;}

  public string Town { get; set;}

  [Required]
  public string Password { get; set;}

}
```

Because `ShoppingCart` implements the `Parent` class, the `ModelState.Valid` is always false because the `Password` is required but I don't populate it with data as it is not needed in the `ShoppingParent` class.

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the `Password` required within the `ShoppingParent` class but keep it required within the `Parent` class.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How about moving common parts to an interface and make both implement it? You cannot do much with inheritance.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Sounds a good idea, I've read about interfaces but still yet don't know much about them so I think im going to struggle adding an interface :/

Comment: You have to either have 2 different base classes or a common interface.

Comment: It's very easy. If you can include the properties in Parent class in your post, I (or somebody) else can post an example.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I've added the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the common properties to an interface and make each one decide if it's required or not.

```
public interface IParent
{
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    string Town { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingParent : IParent
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}


public class PasswordRequiredParent : IParent
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you